# Flutter windows app opens only once and does not create multiple windows upon multiple clicks

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

It's like when the application is opened in the window, and I click the Flutter window app one more time, it should detect whether the app is opened, if already opened, then it shouldn't open the same app in new windows.

What package do I need, and how to integrate it into my project?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.